# Help with interpretation of a zero-inflated gamma model

Tags: interpretation, gamma-distribution, zero-inflation

Background: I'm in fairly over my head here, working on a project for class where we had to choose our own publicly available dataset to analyse and I chose one with a zero-inflated continuous response variable in the form of infection load.

My explanatory variable is categorical with 5 categories. I started by square rooting my response variable to try and reduce the horrible skew and crazy range, I then wanted to run a poisson or zi-poisson but I've been taught they are not happy with non-count/non-integer data and the distribution seemed to fit a gamma distribution. What I went with in the end is a zeroinflated gamma model and I'd really appreciate help interpreting the output of this zero-inflated gamma model I've tried to run.

Am I right in thinking the conditional model section is talking about the probability of each treatment category returning either a zero value or non-zero value and then the zero-inflation model section is the gamma model run on all the non-zero values in each category? To then work out what these values mean I would need to first exponentiate them and then square them, is that right?

Many thanks for any help, any suggestions for simpler models or methods are very welcome.

[image: results in r]